# How to take photo from the webcamera every time I open my MacBook?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook

I want to autotake a photo from the camera on my MacBook Air and put the photo in a folder.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed it is possible. There are several command line utilities that you can use. I have setup a script in my Air to take a picture whenever it wakes up by using [imagesnap](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/macosx/imagesnap/).

You can run imagesnap from an applescript or you can use cron to schedule it to take a picture at a time interval.

Another option would be [EyeSight](http://www.klieme.com/EyeSight.html), which is an app that automates the whole process of taking a picture and saving it to a folder (or upload it via FTP) every N seconds.

Edit: I misread the title of the question and thought you only asked for automated pictures in time intervals.
To answer your question, that is, to take a picture with your Air's cam everytime you open the lid you can use a combination of [imagesnap](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/macosx/imagesnap/) and [sleepwatcher](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/).

Answer (score 0):

You can hack around some solution using [sleepwatcher](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/) and [imagesnap](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/macosx/imagesnap/). Here's the description how to do that: [how to](https://eyetea33.wordpress.com/2013/06/11/take-pictures-using-facetime-hd-or-isight-camera-on-mac-wakeup/)

Or you can use an app that does exactly that - [Selfie App](http://appstore.com/mac/selfieapp) - but it's paid app on the Mac App Store.

Full disclosure: I'm the author of Selfie App

Comment: Thanks for the full disclosure and I realize that your incentive for answering this question probably relates to your app.  That said, this is a link-only answer which will have limited value if any of the links become unavailable.  You do start the answer with a link to a solution.  Please add the essential elements of that link to your answer.  That will make it an acceptable answer on SU so it doesn't get deleted as a link-only answer, plus it will show how much simpler it would be to just use Selfie App.  Win-Win. :-)